# Is concept a variant of SFINAE

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20

SFINAE is a technology that permits invalid expressions and/or types in the immediate context of a templated function while the `concept` seems to have the same effect since we are only permitted to use expressions and types(in *requires-expression*) in the *constraint-expression* of the *concept-definition*, and the constraint-expression is true if all expressions and/or types are valid, and false otherwise. It appears to me that `concept` cannot do anything that exceeds what SFINAE can do, the same is true the other way around.

Is my understanding right? If it is not, what is the case in which we can only by using the concept, or by using SFINAE but using the other way would result in an error? If there does not exist such a scene, is the concept merely a graceful/modern way of using the technology SFINAE(i.e. they are essentially equivalent)?

#### Update:

IMO, the only difference is, certain expressions and types we want to check are dispersed in the declaration for SFINAE, by contrast, certain expressions and types we want to check are collected in the  *constraint-expression* of the single *concept-definition* and use the declared `concept` in the declaration. **Their effect essentially relies on invalid expressions and types**.

Comment: `concept`s are for(along with other things) simplifying your code.

Comment: SFINAE doesn't do subsumption.

Comment: SFINAE is less a technology and more hack of the C++ language.

Comment: @chris What does "subsumption" mean here?

Comment: @xmh0511, It's the idea of one concept being the entirety of another concept plus extra requirements, which affects overloading.

Comment: @bitmask The form of "concept" is so. Invalid expressions and types are the core of SFINAE while invalid expressions and types determine the result of the concept.  They are merely the transformation of the form, I think.

Comment: @chris Yes. However, invalid expressions and types in the concept are other forms of SFINAE, Isn't it?

Comment: Concepts can do one important thing SFINAE cannot, namely be human readable.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, this is the only difference between them I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: @JasonLiam Yes, I didn't negate this point. Technically, I think `concept` and `SFINAE` use the same essence(invalid expressions and types). If any invalid expression and types are produced after the substitution, for SFINAE, the declaration is discarded(SFINAE), and for the concept, the constraint is not satisfied, in general, the declaration is just not viable.

Comment: Yes, concepts are for turning an accidental hack into a first class citizens. It's no coincidence the ideas overlap.

Comment: @StoryTeller-UnslanderMonica So, they are essentially the same without introducing any new technology. They are based on invalid expressions and types, merely, a single concept permits multiple expressions and types in its collection, in order to make code looks elegant, Right?

Comment: No, not quite right. You were already told about subsumption. That *is* "new technology". Not to mention you could portably sfinae on multiple things since C++14 already.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are not equivalent. Concepts can appear in more places and are partially ordered by subsumption. Some examples:

**1. Concept subsumption may be used to rank overloads.** With SFINAE, [this is an error](https://godbolt.org/z/nKePbM95s):

```
template <typename T>
auto overload(T) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>>;
template <typename T>
auto overload(T) -> std::enable_if_t<std::is_move_constructible_v<T>>;

void test() {
  overload(1); // error: ambiguous
}
```

With concepts, [this works](https://godbolt.org/z/x54WesTPT):

```
void overload(std::copy_constructible auto);
void overload(std::move_constructible auto);

void test() {
  overload(1);
}
```

**2. Similarly, concept subsumption may be used to rank partial specializations.**

**3. Concepts are allowed on non-template member functions, so they can constrain special member functions.**

Since a copy constructor is not a template, SFINAE never applies. When one needs conditional behavior before concepts (e.g. trivial copy constructor if the template argument of the class template is itself trivial), one had to conditionally introduce different base classes.

**4. Concepts can constrain deduction.**

One can statically assert that a type returned satisfies your requirements without asserting the precise type.

```
std::integral auto i = 1;
```

**5. Concepts can be used in abbreviated function templates.**

```
void f(std::integral auto);
```

Comment: Ah, concepts have the partial ordering relationship defined in [temp.constr.order], for which SFINAE cannot implement. You also list many contexts in which SFINAE is not possible to be used, thanks.